# Laravel passport no retorna accessToken como JWT

Tags: laravel, json, jwt, passport

Estoy creando un token de acceso para mi usuario en passport y en vez de obtener un `string` de `JWT` estoy obteniendo los datos del token en formato `json` ¿Por qué pasa esto?

Creación del token:

```
if(Auth::attempt($credentials)){
    $user = Auth::user();
    $token = $user->createToken('My Token', ['read-phrase'])->accessToken;
    return response()->json(["token" => $token]);
}
```

La variable `$token` queda como una instancia de `Laravel\Sanctum\PersonalAccessToken`

Lo que obtengo como respuesta del llamado a `createToken()`

```
Laravel\Sanctum\NewAccessToken {#1415
  +accessToken: Laravel\Sanctum\PersonalAccessToken {#478
    #casts: array:2 [
      "abilities" => "json"
      "last_used_at" => "datetime"
    ]
    #fillable: array:3 [
      0 => "name"
      1 => "token"
      2 => "abilities"
    ]
    #hidden: array:1 [
      0 => "token"
    ]
    #connection: "mysql"
    #table: "personal_access_tokens"
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #keyType: "int"
    +incrementing: true
    #with: []
    #withCount: []
    #perPage: 15
    +exists: true
    +wasRecentlyCreated: true
    #attributes: array:8 [
      "name" => "My Token"
      "token" => "8063ed4786de4e6ad31a3d355dcc65463db2d6902d84f41d4cc85752fe90b87d"
      "abilities" => "["read-phrase"]"
      "tokenable_id" => "00d1783b-6904-492a-a249-b4e85a3ec70c"
      "tokenable_type" => "App\Models\User"
      "updated_at" => "2020-10-15 21:30:17"
      "created_at" => "2020-10-15 21:30:17"
      "id" => 8
    ]
    #original: array:8 [
      "name" => "My Token"
      "token" => "8063ed4786de4e6ad31a3d355dcc65463db2d6902d84f41d4cc85752fe90b87d"
      "abilities" => "["read-phrase"]"
      "tokenable_id" => "00d1783b-6904-492a-a249-b4e85a3ec70c"
      "tokenable_type" => "App\Models\User"
      "updated_at" => "2020-10-15 21:30:17"
      "created_at" => "2020-10-15 21:30:17"
      "id" => 8
    ]
    #changes: []
    #classCastCache: []
    #dates: []
    #dateFormat: null
    #appends: []
    #dispatchesEvents: []
    #observables: []
    #relations: []
    #touches: []
    +timestamps: true
    #visible: []
    #guarded: array:1 [
      0 => "*"
    ]
  }
  +plainTextToken: "8|IFDDKth2llbJpG9SgCDXaAWj19KekEhFlCrvDLRW"
}
```

La documentación de passport indica que para obtener el token hay que llamar posteriormente a  `->accessToken;`, lo que me retorna:

```
Laravel\Sanctum\PersonalAccessToken {#478
  #casts: array:2 [
    "abilities" => "json"
    "last_used_at" => "datetime"
  ]
  #fillable: array:3 [
    0 => "name"
    1 => "token"
    2 => "abilities"
  ]
  #hidden: array:1 [
    0 => "token"
  ]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "personal_access_tokens"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: true
  #attributes: array:8 [
    "name" => "My Token"
    "token" => "23b10620f2e7b0f59e17337ba2d7b1a2da5ccbfea7a1fc0c95d4ca76f7d8eeb8"
    "abilities" => "["read-phrase"]"
    "tokenable_id" => "00d1783b-6904-492a-a249-b4e85a3ec70c"
    "tokenable_type" => "App\Models\User"
    "updated_at" => "2020-10-15 21:31:52"
    "created_at" => "2020-10-15 21:31:52"
    "id" => 9
  ]
  #original: array:8 [
    "name" => "My Token"
    "token" => "23b10620f2e7b0f59e17337ba2d7b1a2da5ccbfea7a1fc0c95d4ca76f7d8eeb8"
    "abilities" => "["read-phrase"]"
    "tokenable_id" => "00d1783b-6904-492a-a249-b4e85a3ec70c"
    "tokenable_type" => "App\Models\User"
    "updated_at" => "2020-10-15 21:31:52"
    "created_at" => "2020-10-15 21:31:52"
    "id" => 9
  ]
  #changes: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [
    0 => "*"
  ]
}
```

He probado con una instalación totalmente limpia de laravel y passport y me ha entregado el JWT sin mayores problemas.

La salida del llamado a `$user->createToken('My Token')->accessToken;` es un JWT como el siguiente:

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianRpIjoiN2ZmNjc1Nzc4YzQ5YTY0NjllMWM0ZjhjNWY1YmI0YTEwZTIxZWI3Y2Q2NGYyNzk4MWNhYWNjY2U3NDZjZWYxNmVhY2U4NGJhNWFjZGVjNzMiLCJpYXQiOjE2MDI3OTc1NzAsIm5iZiI6MTYwMjc5NzU3MCwiZXhwIjoxNjM0MzMzNTcwLCJzdWIiOiIxIiwic2NvcGVzIjpbXX0.n-XfuB0iqFxkLdWP925OuIC9Qdsm3nTCPuoIOEyStPf4udd6ym8xVQO6ivExVsLKZPpp__ZUl1xl8MqDLu5bCwrI7prpWKdd6fXtlmorqUNWQ6TJ65ZckBWdCdOs2Stxp8t_8Ojbkpid933ZkA3lyxQIz-h25_axG8ghciftWxfC5awOuKBq4r6PQggXGu9zJdkHdvoRr9YiqysmnSABRj4VqM_Rg5CDIoQ5bpVU8M3VYrYtQ6cgkb5vFP9L4_h7dEvW7LvBXOd8liM5dLVd8o4muok1DieGBDx85Kc_v3tPsUMw5j84rI5LPIKghvmxt637hmASxANoQ1LVSky7fpPOjVSyq2gJ0UO-HrBXtGIkZmEMiEe2Nh307cF6x5ZUPAYa7UhzZETrQAqid8j25gTdu2OxjOfudIZUJPs2WowXSImikEHvKYNv7up96wX3ZpQjsCFeODSlL-G2_wLjtRt_EBM7KwEugylDPydHaKa8iI6LTbFVmP400l3eONwNRcVCzUUMjV3rf5snp2boYTP07kdqcslXc88UPrSNgyEOCUmS8xeaAgbLOiM3fAyfzBSe4qJIoEIb1HH78eGYsH93A_Ae6GdF0GJBReCXyebVdBG2SvoOINZu7tIQYDfuX_HGFMiccnZrdltYOD7gm7xoC4oJ_38OPot9mcNRusE
```

La diferencia entre la instalación limpia y mi "aplicación" es la siguiente:

1.- Estoy utilizando UUID para los usuarios y passport

2.- Instalé Jetstream

3.- Instalé LightHouse (Graphql)

¿Cómo puedo darle el formato correspondiente a mi token para luego utilizarlos en los headers con Bearer?

Comment: A qué te refieres con "formato correspondiente", qué formato esperas?

Comment: Un string en formato JWT (Json Web Token)

Comment: Verificaste que tu modelo User tenga HasApiTokens?

Comment: Si, efectivamente ahí estaba el error, he publicado una respuesta, aún tengo dudas de como pudo pasar el problema, si crees poder complementar la respuesta seria genial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me percaté que la importación del `trait` en la clase `User` era incorrecto en relación a lo que mencionaba la documentación de passport.
Es posible que esta importación la haya realizado la instalación de jetstream (*Pero no estoy seguro de que eso haya sido así, quizá fue una mala jugada del editor de codigo*).

Actualmente tenia

```
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
```

Luego de cambiar la importación por lo mencionado en passport todo volvió a funcionar como se esperaba.

```
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
```

Answer (score 0):

El método `createToken()` en **Passport** retorna una instancia de `PersonalAccessTokenResult` el cual a su vez implementa `Arrayable` y `Jsonable`, por lo que puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
$user->createToken('My Token', ['read-phrase'])->toArray();

$user->createToken('My Token', ['read-phrase'])->toJson();
```

Dependiendo de tus necesidades.

Comment: El método ````createToken()```` me está retornando una instancia de ````PersonalAccessToken````, las llamadas ````->toArray()```` y ````->toJson()```` no solucionaron el problema, actualizaré la pregunta con las salidas y mayor documentación del problema.

Answer (score 0):

Te muestro un ejemplo que viene en la documentación:

```php
$token = $user->createToken('token-name');
return $token->plainTextToken;
```

Así mismo, adaptado al flujo de tu código, quedaría así:

```php
if( Auth::attempt($credentials) ){
    $user = Auth::user();
    $token = $user->createToken('My Token', ['read-phrase']);
    return response()->json(["token" => $token->plainTextToken]);
}
```

Por cierto, el objeto que regresa la función `createToken` debe ser una instancia de `Laravel\Sanctum\NewAccessToken`, te recomiendo que revises tu configuración.

Comment: El ````createToken```` efectivamente es una instancia de ````NewAccessToken````. En la documentación de passport utilizan ````accessToken```` (El cual retorna un JWT) y no ````plainTextToken````. 

Probé una instalación limpia de passport y obtengo el JWT sin problemas, la única diferencia en configuración con mi aplicación es que mi aplicación trabaja la ID del usuario como UUID y de igual forma he instalado jetstream. ¿Puede algo de eso dar colisión? Cuando hablas de configuración, ¿Puedes ser más especifico?

Comment: Mencionaba la configuración porque me daba la impresión de que estaba regresando una instancia de determinada clase que no era la correcta. En cuanto a qué me refiero con configuración, quiero decir: cuando das de alta los middlewares, providers... etc.