# Laravel 8 Passport - Gestion de token para las autorizaciones de rutas protegidas

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-8, passport, oauth2

me dispongo a usar el paquete **passport** de laravel, para todo el tema de gestion de autorizaciones,etc.. para mi API. Yo ya user dicho paquete anteriormente, pero esta vez lo encuentro algo diferente.

A mi funcion de hacer login, le he puesto que genere un token con nombre **auth** asociado al usuario en cuestion:

```
   public function login(Request $request){

    $validation = Validator::make($request->all(),['name'=>'required','password'=>'required']);
    $name = $request->get('name');
    $password = $request->get('password');

    if ($validation->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['message'=>$validation->errors()], 400);
    }

    $user = User::where('name',$name)->first();

    if (Hash::check($password, $user->password)) {
        $token = $user->createToken('auth');
        return response()->json(['message'=>'Ha iniciado sesión correctamente.','token'=>$token])   ;
    }
    else{
        return response()->json(['message'=>'Error al iniciar sesión.'],400);
    }
}
```

El `$token` tambien he probado a cambiarlo por : `$token = $user->createToken('auth')->accessToken` pero no era lo que yo esperaba, yo recordaba los tokens asi : `Bearer 2342rf34rf3fdc...etc`  pero  no se si es un token Bearer ni nada.

Por otro lado, en las rutas protegidas tengo el `middleware` y todo correctamente:

```
//Auth routes
Route::group(['prefix'=>'/auth','name'=>'auth.','middleware'=>'auth:api'],function () {

    //User routes
    Route::group(['prefix'=>'/user'],function () {
        Route::get('/profile', [UserController::class,'profile'])->name('profile');
    });
});
```

En definitiva esa ruta corresponde a la URI: `http:(host)/auth/user/profile` , que corresponderia al perfil del usuario y por tanto es privado y unica forma de acceder seria el token que pillo al hacer login.

---

### Pruebas

Segun lo que tengo puesto para el login, el response al `/login` es :

```
{
    "message": "Ha iniciado sesión correctamente.",
    "token": {
        "accessToken": {
            "name": "auth",
            "abilities": [
                "*"
            ],
            "tokenable_id": 1,
            "tokenable_type": "App\\Models\\User",
            "updated_at": "2021-11-06T21:41:31.000000Z",
            "created_at": "2021-11-06T21:41:31.000000Z",
            "id": 38
        },
        "plainTextToken": "38|0Rng0bhztP0zHKdxgK3LxTC7E95MensAeK7wNCQ8"
    }
}
```

Lo noto un poco cambiado a lo que recordaba, pero supongo que con eso es lo que tengo que jugar para las autorizaciones, recordemos que `token` el lo que retornaba : `$user->createToken('auth');` . Parece que el token es lo que viene en `plainTextToken` pero he probado de mil formas diferentes en el **postman** para poder acceder a la ruta `profile` , que recordemos que esta protegida, y no hay manera.

### En postman..

Intento acceder a  : `localhost/gua_back/auth/user/profile` , pero claro de alguna forma le tengo que meter el token ese que me da el login, pues me da este error el postman :

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException: The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. in file /var/www/html/gua_back/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/AbstractRouteCollection.php on line 117
```

En principio ese error me lo da porque le tengo puesto a las rutas:

```
...group(['prefix'=>'/auth','name'=>'auth.','middleware'=>'auth:api']...
```

este es el culpable:

```
..'middleware'=>'auth:api'].
```

Entiendo que le tengo que pasar el token, pero de mil maneras he probado y no funciona, definitivamente no es como el Bearer Token que tenia antes.

Comment: Quizá la respuesta está en esta pregunta que elaboré hace un tiempo. [Laravel passport no retorna accessToken como JWT](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/398502/laravel-passport-no-retorna-accesstoken-como-jwt)

Comment: Recuerda que passport entrega una integración completa de Oauth, si solo buscas tokens de accesos con scopes, puedes utilizar [sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum)

Comment: Efectivamente,  `sanctum`  aplica justo lo que necesitaba, practicamente iban de la mano pero estaba usando el middleware de autenticacion erroneo. Gracias por tu respuesta pues me ha ayudado a aclararme bastante.